# PHP - Change color icon class in relation to the result of a query

Tags: php, sql

I would like to change the color of my icon based on the result of my query

```
<?php
$rich_tkn = 'Richiedente Token';
$result="SELECT count('id_token_gen')
                 FROM token_gen
                 WHERE richiesta_token =  '$rich_tkn' ";
$sql=mysqli_query($connessione,$result);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

?>
```

color change instructions

```
<?php
if ($sql == 0){
    echo 'zero<p style="float: left;" class="card-img-top"><i class="far fa-clock fa-3x grey-text"></i></p>';
}else{
    echo '+zero<p style="float: left;" class="card-img-top"><i class="far fa-clock fa-3x red-text"></i></p>';
}
?>
```

at this time both if the result is zero or it is not, I always have to dsiplay the instructions contained in the else.

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<?php
if ($sql == 0){
    echo 'zero<p style="float: left;" class="card-img-top"><i class="far fa-clock fa-3x grey-text"></i></p>';
}else{
    echo '+zero<p style="float: left;" class="card-img-top"><i class="far fa-clock fa-3x red-text"></i></p>';
}
?>
```

To

```
<?php
if ($row[0] == 0){
    echo 'zero<p style="float: left;" class="card-img-top"><i class="far fa-clock fa-3x grey-text"></i></p>';
}else{
    echo '+zero<p style="float: left;" class="card-img-top"><i class="far fa-clock fa-3x red-text"></i></p>';
}
?>
```

The change is using variable $row which has your SQL query results, and first element of that row (index 0) has the value of your query - count('id_token_gen')

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns a mysqli_result object, which will never equal 0. Instead you want to check if the first array value of your $row variable is equal to 0 like so `array_first($row) === 0`.

In addition, your mysql maybe not be what you intended, though your query *should* still work. You're counting on a string, when I assume you're intending to count on the column `id_token_gen`. Either `count(*)` or `` count(`id_token_gen`) `` would work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, if there are no results, the first text should be printed, otherwise, the second one. So, in that case:

Instead of

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

Replace with

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

And below, instead of

```
if ($sql == 0){
```

Replace with

```
if ($rowcount == 0){
```